# Como eu faço um POST + Redirect com Angular?

Tags: http, angular

Olá,
Preciso fazer um post para uma pagina e redirecionar junto com o post para quando carregar a pagina exibir os dados postados.

O problema é que quando faço o post ele já me traz o RESPONSE com os dados carregados e se eu fizer o redirect vou estar fazendo um GET.

Tem como postar e abrir a pagina na mesma requisição?

```
var data = {
    'nomede' :'Paulo',
    'emailde':'paulo@gmail.com',
    'sobrenomede':'Sousa',
    'sapde':'19811',
    'nomepara':'João',
    'emailpara':'joao@gmail.com'
}

$http({
    url: 'http://pagina.com',
    method: "POST",
    params: data
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    $window.location.href = 'http://pagina.com';
},
function (response) { // optional
    // failed
});
```

Eu consigo fazer isso facilmente com JQUERY

```
var form = '';
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
form += '<input type="hidden" name="' + key + '" value="' + value + '">';
});
$('<form action="' + url + '" method="POST">' + form + '</form>').appendTo('body').submit();
```

Comment: Paulo, estou fazendo um curso na Udemy e recentemente fiz um post. O código está aqui: https://github.com/mMarcos208/MeuAppAngularUdemy/blob/master/src/app/order/orderService.ts
Quem sabe possa lhe ajudar.

Comment: @Marconi Isso é Angular 2?

Comment: Angular 4, o curso é esse:  [Construindo Aplicações Web Com o Novo Angular 4](https://www.udemy.com/angular-pt/learn/v4)

Comment: Acho que não vou trocar o framework só por isso, mas obrigado de qualquer  forma